# Trying to make a plot of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

https://data.cdc.gov/Case-Surveillance/United-States-COVID-19-Cases-and-Deaths-by-State-o/9mfq-cb36
Using the data from link above.
Want to make a graph of the weekly average of new cases in Iowa but am running into issues when I try to format the date.
My code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as mp

d = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\me\Downloads\final_project_data.csv') #import csv file
d# print csv file to make sure everything is correct



state = "IA" #put abriviation of choosen state here
data = data.loc[d["state"] == state] # locate all data points where the state is the choosen state
data
```

Here is what I have tried to format the date so I can make a weekly moving average.

```
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["submission_date"])
```

Using the above method I get an error of

```
<ipython-input-22-938db9badc5a>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["submission_date"])
```

I then tried another method

```
data['submission_date']= pd.to_datetime(data['submission_date'],format='%mm%dd%yyyy') # converts date to datetime field
data = reset_my_index(data) # reverse order of dataframe so later dates are last
data = data.loc[:,['submission_date','new_case']] # select columns to work with
```

This cave me the error message of

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    449             try:
--> 450                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    451                 dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-39ff0f95742c> in <module>
----> 1 data['submission_date']= pd.to_datetime(data['submission_date'],format='%mm%dd%yyyy') # converts date to datetime field
      2 data = reset_my_index(data) # reverse order of dataframe so later dates are last
      3 data = data.loc[:,['submission_date','new_case']] # select columns to work with

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    801             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    802         else:
--> 803             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    804             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    805     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    452                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dta, name=name)
    453             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 454                 raise e
    455 
    456     if result is None:

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    415             if result is None:
    416                 try:
--> 417                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
    418                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    419                     )

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '06/02/2020' does not match format '%mm%dd%yyyy' (match)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am running out of ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This fix is simple - you need to reset the index of the `data` dataframe. See the below code.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as mp

d = pd.read_csv (r'covid.csv') #import csv file

state = "IA" #put abriviation of choosen state here
data = d.loc[d["state"] == state] # locate all data points where the state is the choosen state
data = data.reset_index() # Reset the index
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["submission_date"]) # no error should occur now
```

I believe your error states why this happened: when you created `data = d.loc[d["state"] == state]`, you were taking a slice of the original dataframe and attempting to assign a value to it from that same slice.